# Finding the table free time using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query that provides Waiter's free time, in a day between two customers. When I change the columns to get the results for table free time, I am not getting the proper results.Any suggestions?

Below is the query for Waiter's free time:-

```
Declare @start date, @end date
set @start='03/03/2019'
set @end='03/03/2020';

with
t as (
    SELECT DISTINCT
            Table_No,
            Customer_In_Time, 
            Customer_Out_Time,
            Date,
            row_number() over (partition by Name order by Name, Customer_In_time) rn
    FROM Hotel
    
)
select Table_No,Customer_In_Time,Customer_Out_Time,
       coalesce(sum(datediff(minute, prev_cot, Customer_in_time)), 0) as free_minutes
from (select t.*,
             tprev.Customer_out_time as prev_cot
      from t outer apply
           (select top (1) t2.*
                from t t2
                where t2.Table_No= t.Table_No and t2.date = t.date and
                      t2.Table_In_Time < t.Table_In_Time and
                      t2.rn+1 = t.rn
                order BY t.Room_no, t2.Patient_in_time 
           ) tprev
     ) t
     where t.date between @start and @end
     and Table_No is not Null
group by Table_No, Customer_In_Time,Customer_Out_Time,
 order by t.Table_no,t.Customer_In_time
```

Data:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+  
| Name              Customer_In_Time         Customer_Out_Time    Free Time  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Nikhil, Tiwari    2020-03-03 14:30:00.000   2020-03-03 15:11:00.000   0    |
| Ayish, Jain       2020-03-03 08:10:00.000   2020-03-03 08:35:46.650   0    |
| Ayish, Jain       2020-03-03 08:33:12.000   2020-03-03 09:35:02.000   -2   |
| Ayish, Jain       2020-03-03 09:22:00.000   2020-03-03 10:30:19.447   47   |
| Ayish, Jain       2020-03-03 11:54:24.000   2020-03-03 13:44:07.000   199  |
| Ayish, Jain       2020-03-03 14:16:04.000   2020-03-03 16:23:01.000   341  |
| Harsh,Gupta       2020-03-03 07:34:52.000   2020-03-03 08:48:47.000   0    |
| Harsh,Gupta       2020-03-03 10:30:31.000   2020-03-03 11:48:26.000   102  |
| Harsh,Gupta       2020-03-03 12:37:43.000   2020-03-03 13:35:43.000   229  |
```

Comment: we can't determin what is wron, without knowing where you data come frome and what the result shpuld be please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAG()`. For example:

```
select
  name,
  customer_in_time,
  customer_out_time,
  timestampdiff(minute, 
    lag(customer_in_time) over(partition by name order by customer_in_time),
    customer_out_time
  ) as free_time
from hotel
```

**Note**: This query will produce `null` for the first row of each partition, since there's no time difference for it. If you want to replace it by a zero, you can use `COALESCE()`.